# Rails, trying to avoid duplicating code (lists of URLs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, collections, controller

I'm trying to simplify and DRY up my rails code so as not to duplicate lists of URLs in multiple places and have to keep them in sync. I have a static_pages controller with a method *parent* that has instance variables for lists of urls in different categories, i.e.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def parent
    @collection1 = [
      ["Link 1", "http://link1.com"],   
      ["Link 2", "http://link2.com"] 
    ]
    @collection2 = [
      ["Link 3", "http://link3.com"],   
      ["Link 4", "http://link4.com"] 
    ]
  end
end
```

Then in my static_pages/views folder I have a file
**parent.html.erb**
with code

```
<% @collection1.each do |link| %> 
  <a href="<%= link[1] %>" target = "_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><%= link[0] %></a>
<% @collection2.each do |link| %> 
  <a href="<%= link[1] %>" target = "_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><%= link[0] %></a>
```

But I have another view in static_pages, **child.html.erb** that I want to just display collection 1

```
<% @collection1.each do |link| %> 
  <a href="<%= link[1] %>" target = "_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><%= link[0] %></a>
```

But in order to do this I have to define another method in the same controller:

```
def child
  @collection1 = [
    ["Link 1", "http://link1.com"],   
    ["Link 2", "http://link2.com"] 
  ]
end
```

which is the same collection as I have in the parent method. That works but then if I want to change one the links I have to change it in both places. Please advise, I am pretty new to rails but realize this can't possibly be the way you're supposed to this! Thank you.

My routes.rb is simple

```
get '/parent', to: 'static_pages#parent'
get '/child',  to: 'static_pages#child'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model `Collections` who can save your URL collections and then in your controller, child and parents, call you retrieve the collections like :

```
@collections1 = Collections.find(1)
```

or

```
@collections1 - Collections.where(:collections => 1)
```

After this is up to you to how conceive your Model.